# Keeping a running Total with Random numbers in while loop, c++

Tags: c++

Im suppose to make a simplified version of the game blackjack. The program wont keep the running total after the first iteration of giving me a new card. Ive tried NewestTotal=NewTotal+Ncard, but it seems the random nature of Ncard isnt taking. How do I solidify the first iteration of Ncard and then add a new Ncard to the total. Keeping a running total after every loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //constants
    const int MIN_VALUE = 1; // min card roll
    const int MAX_VALUE = 10; // max card roll
    
    //variables
    int card1; //to hold value of card #1
    int card2; //to hold value of card #2
    int Ncard;
    int total=0;
    char Again;
    int bust=22;
    int NewTotal;
    int NewestTotal;

    unsigned seed = time(0);
    
    srand(seed);//seed random number genrortor
  
    card1=(rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE+1))+MIN_VALUE;
    card2=(rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE+1))+MIN_VALUE;
   
    cout<<"First cards: ";
    cout<<card1<<", ";
    cout<<card2<<"\n";
    total=card1+card2;
    cout<<"Total is "<<total<<"\n";

        do{
            Ncard=(rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE+1))+MIN_VALUE;
            NewTotal=total+Ncard;
          //NewestTotal=NewTotal+Ncard;
          
            cout<<"Do you want another card? (y,n)";
            cin>>Again;
            
          
            if(Again=='n')
                cout<<"You stay. Total is ";
          
            if(Again=='y')
                cout<<"New card is "<<Ncard<<"\n";

            if(NewTotal>=bust)
                cout<<"Bust!";

          
          cout<<"Total is "<<NewestTotal<<endl;
           //?is this just NewTotal?

        }while(Again!='n' || Again=='y');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to the code? Please do not use `rand()` , use `<random`> standard library. Hint: To which values have you initialized the variables?

Comment: The documentation (with examples) is [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) Each of the engine documentation also provides an example for that engine, e.g. [std::mersenne_twister_engine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)

Comment: A running total is normally kept this way: `total = total + newValue;` or shorter `total += newValue;`

Comment: Im not sure what debugging is ill look it up. The rand() is from the book and what i was told to use but i will look up<random> in hopes it will work for me. If write the total like that i get a high number. Thank you for the responses ill look into them